# Random crash in webCore, see call stack, how to debug?

Tags: iphone, crash

Iphone simulator crash in thread 7 (web thread), app use webview, interact with other views using phoneGap.

Based on XCode 4.2.

```
#0  0x05841d8a in WebCore::ApplicationCacheGroup::disassociateDocumentLoader ()
#1  0x056879fa in WebCore::ApplicationCacheHost::~ApplicationCacheHost ()
#2  0x0568714f in WebCore::DocumentLoader::~DocumentLoader ()
#3  0x053decb0 in WebDocumentLoaderMac::~WebDocumentLoaderMac ()
#4  0x0579f405 in WebCore::FrameLoader::detachViewsAndDocumentLoader ()
#5  0x0577a542 in WebCore::FrameLoader::detachFromParent ()
#6  0x054414d1 in -[WebView(WebPrivate) _close] ()
#7  0x0459567d in __invoking___ ()
#8  0x04595551 in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()
#9  0x055983c3 in HandleAPISource ()
#10 0x0460601f in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#11 0x0456419d in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#12 0x04563786 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#13 0x04563240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#14 0x04563161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#15 0x05659423 in RunWebThread ()
#16 0x98305259 in _pthread_start ()
#17 0x983050de in thread_start ()
```